# How to restrict android app to specific brands?

Tags: android, google-play

I am developing an android app for only samsung brand of phones - that's the project requirement.

So I need to be able to make the app available in the android marketplace only to those devices that are produced by SAMSUNG manufacturer.

I don't seem to be able to find how to do that.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "Device Catalogue" in the Play Console to exclude all non Samsung devices:

[image]

Please note you'll have to regular check and update this list as new devices are released.

Comment: Hi Ian, first thanks a lot for your response! Really helps me a lot. One question, do I have to exclude one by one the devices? or is there a way to exclude brands or larger groups?

Comment: @SusanaMoreno Unfortunately I don't know of any way of making this easier than doing it one by one. The Play console does have an API, I had a quick look but didn't find an easier to do what you're looking for: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher

Comment: Thanks a lot Ian! Help me a lot your comment!

Comment: @SusanaMoreno Glad I could help! Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if you think it's the correct one.